# Add google analytics for separate clients with one build

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a JS web application that I build once and ship to different clients. By ship I mean that I have the same build for them all, but I create a separate deployment and each deployment has its own domain name. Every client gets my app by logging to their deployment through the individual link.

I want to add google analytics to that so I know the usage of every client.

I want to do that by building just once and deploying the same build for everyone. (One executable not different for every client).

If I create separate properties in Google Analytics, I will have to build separately for everyone. Tagging every build for every client differently.

What is the right way to do what I need?

Edit:

My application is purely frontend and doesn't have backend.

Comment: [Use environment variables?](https://www.seancdavis.com/posts/set-env-var-js-projects/)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: From the linked article: _"[Environment variables](https://www.seancdavis.com/posts/wtf-is-environment-variable/) are a great way to store values that will change based on your program's context (local vs production), or values that are sensitive and shouldn't be coupled with the code. (See here for more info on [when to use environment variables](https://www.seancdavis.com/posts/when-to-use-environment-variables/).)"_ (this can be for both front and back end)

Answer (score 0):

as understand you want to have single GA and see stats per client how they use the app. You mentioned each client has different domain, so domain is identifier here. You can set user_id at data layer for GA4.

Just read the domain and use domain as user_id, you will be able to filter data by user id.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/user-id?platform=websites

```js
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX', {
'user_id': location.hostname 
});
```